# convert javascript date to php Y-m-d

Tags: php, date, datetime

I try to convert an javascript date with php to Y-m-d but it's not working proper.

```
$to = 'Wed Jul 01 2020 15:09:00 GMT 0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)';
$to = substr($to, 0, strpos($to, '('));
$to = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($to));

echo $to;
```

result is:`0300-07-04`

Comment: With only `Jul 01 2020 15:09:00` in `$to` the strtotime will return the right date. Maybe try to use some Regex to get only that part Or adjust your substr function

Comment: I don't understand the JavaScript part ? The output you're looking for is 2020-07-01 ?

Comment: @executable what their $to contains, is the default format you get when a JS `Date` object is put into a string context. Other than that this is their input format, the question does not appear to have anything to do with JS.

Comment: and the q don't deserve -1 as well , u guys give -1 to each and every question

Comment: @aryanagarwal problems such as this could do with a bit more attention (on the part of the person having them), than just “tried something, did not work, now you make for me.” What date formats strtotime _can_ understand, is documented.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the substr so it will get the right part of the date string that can be ussed in `strtotime()`. Maybe some one know a better way because using this doent feel right in my opinion.

```
$to = 'Wed Jul 01 2020 15:09:00 GMT 0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)';
$to = substr($to, 3, strpos($to, 'GMT'));
$to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($to));

echo $to;
```